# Should traceroute be used to diagnose network latency issues?

Tags: linux-networking, ping, latency, traceroute

I ran the `traceroute` command from `Server A` to `Server B`, two of the hops display a latency between 250ms to 480ms.

However when running `ping` from `Server A` to `Server B`, the response is always within 1ms.

My network admin team is of the opinion that there are no issues since `ping` always responds back with 1ms and the latency observed via `traceroute` should't be considered.

How do I rule out network latency issues?

Comment: Where are the servers located in relation to each other?

Comment: Both servers are within my organisation, however the physical locations differ. I don't have the exact details, all I tell you is that traceroute takes 9 hops to reach server B from server A.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I'm not sure you've provided enough information or detail to allow us to help you.

Comment: @ewwhite Since `traceroute` shows a latency and `ping` doesn't, I was wondering which one of the two is a better indication of network issues. Can the latency by `traceroute` be ignored since `ping` seems to be returning within 1ms?

Comment: `Should traceroute be used to diagnose network latency issues?` - No it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traceroute is not a good measure of end to end latency because many routers in the forwarding path purposefully rate-limit ICMP traffic. If you are consitently getting a <1ms response between your two servers, it sounds like you have already ruled out a network latency issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `mtr` command, as it can show you the latency between source and destination.

Comment: Unfortunately `mtr` isn't installed, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Oliver You would need to install `mtr` in order to use it.

Comment: yup I got that, but installing new tools in the production environment isn't an option. Thank you.